# Scores of black and white marks

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

We have a connected (undirected) graph with $n$ vertices, and $b$ black and $w$ white marks with $b+w=n$ and $\max(b,w)\geq 2$. In a placement of the marks on the vertices, the "score" of a mark is the ratio of its neighbors of the same color to its total neighbors (this ratio is always well-defined due to connectivity). A placement is called "nice" if it is not possible to rearrange the marks so that every mark gets a better or same score as before, and at least one mark gets a better score.

Is it true that in any nice placement, the sum of the scores is at least $1$?

The score may be $1$, if the graph is a triangle and $b=2,w=1$.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is true.

Let $G$ be our graph, $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$ be its vertices, and $(d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n)$ be the corresponding sequence of their degrees. Any placement $p$ of $b$ black and $w$ white marks also induces the corresponding sequence $(p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n)$, where $p_i$ is the number of vertices adjacent to $v_i$ and having the same color as $v_i$.

**Definition 1.** We say that a placement $q$ *majorizes* $p$, if it contains the same numbers of black and white marks as $p$ and induces the sequence $(q_1, q_2, \dots, q_n)$, where $\forall i \colon q_i \ge p_i$ and $q_i > p_i$ for at least one $i$.

The statement in question is equivalent to the claim that if

$$\frac {p_1}{d_1} + \frac {p_2}{d_2} + \dots + \frac {p_n}{d_n} < 1\,, \tag{1}$$

then there is a placement $q$ that majorizes $p$.

To prove it, first note that $(1)$ implies $\min(b,w) \ge 1$, otherwise every summand at the left-hand side of $(1)$ would be $1$ and the sum would be the natural number $n$. This also means that

$$n = b + w = \min(b, w) + \max(b, w) \ge 1 + 2 = 3\,. \tag{2}$$

Consider the spanning subgraph $H$ of $G$ that contains only edges connecting equally colored (by $p$) vertices of $G$. It breaks down into several connected components (whereas $G$ was connected). Note that each component contains only vertices of one color. We number the black components: $\mathcal B = \{B_1, B_2, \dots, B_t\}$. If $b_i = |B_i|$ are their sizes (in set theory terms), then $b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_t = b$. Also do the same for the white components: $\mathcal W = \{W_1, W_2, \dots, W_s\}$. If $w_i = |W_i|$, then $w_1 + w_2 + \dots + w_s = w$. Let $k = t + s$ be the total number of components and $e$ be the total number of edges in $H$. Since a component with $r$ vertices contains at least $r - 1$ edges, summing this for all components, we obtain: $e \ge n - k$. On the other hand, $2e = p_1 + p_2 + \dots + p_n$. Since each $d_i \le n - 1$, from $(1)$ we have: $\frac {2e}{n - 1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {p_i}{n - 1} \le \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {p_i}{d_i} < 1$, thus $2e < n - 1,$ $2n - 2k \le 2e \le n - 2$ and $$n \le 2k - 2\,. \tag{3}$$

Note that $k$ is the quantity of the numbers $b_i, w_i$ and $n$ is their sum. Thus $(3)$, in particular, implies that their average $\frac n k$ is less than $2$. Therefore, at least one of them is $1$. WLOG, $b_1 = 1$. Let $u \ge 1$ be the total number of units among $b_i$. The remaining $t - u$ numbers are $2$ or greater, hence $b = b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_t \ge u + 2(t - u) = 2t - u$. Let $m = \min (w_1, w_2, \dots, w_s)$. Then $w = w_1 + w_2 + \dots + w_s \ge ms$. From this and $(3)$: $2(t + s) - 2 \ge b + w \ge (2t - u) + ms$, thus $u - 2 \ge (m - 2)s$. We conclude that the case $m > u$ is impossible since then $m - 2 > u - 2 \ge (m - 2)s$ and $0 > (m - 2)(s - 1)$, but $m \ge u + 1 \ge 2$ and $s \ge 1$. Therefore,

$$u \ge m\,. \tag{4}$$

The key part of the upcoming reasoning is based on the following definition and lemma.

**Definition 2.** A placement $p$ is called *sub-balanced* if there are two sets, $\mathcal B\,' \subseteq \mathcal B$ and $\mathcal W\,' \subseteq \mathcal W$ such that $\mathcal B\,' \cup \mathcal W\,'$ is a proper nonempty subset of $\mathcal B \cup \mathcal W$ and the total number of vertices in components from $\mathcal B\,'$ is equal to the total number of vertices in components from $\mathcal W\,'$.

**Lemma.** If $p$ is sub-balanced, then it isn't nice, i.e. there is another placement that majorizes it.

**Proof.** Let $p$ be sub-balanced. Denote by $V$ the set of all vertices contained in components from $\mathcal B\,' \cup \mathcal W\,'$. We compose the placement $q$ by simply changing colors of all vertices in $V$, i.e. from black to white in $\mathcal B\,'$ and from white to black in $\mathcal W\,'$. The ratio of black and white vertices remains unchanged. If $v_i$ was in some component $B_j$ or $W_j$, then all vertices counted by $p_i$ were in the same component. Its color may have changed, but all these vertices still have the same color in $q$, therefore $\forall i \colon q_i \ge p_i$. To prove that $q_i > p_i$ for some $i$, take two vertices, one of which is from $V$ and the other is not (this is possible because $V$ is a proper nonempty subset of $G$'s vertices). $G$ is connected, therefore we can connect these vertices by a path in $G$. There is an edge $(v_i, v_j)$ in this path such that $v_i \in V$ and $v_j \notin V\!.$ $v_i$ and $v_j$ were of different colors in $p$ because otherwise $v_j$ should have been in the same component as $v_i$ and therefore should have belonged to $V$. But now, as long as the color of $v_i$ has changed and the color of $v_j$ has not, $v_i$ and $v_j$ have the same color; hence $q_i > p_i$ and $q_j > p_j$. ∎

From this point on, we simply apply the lemma for the cases when $p$ is sub-balanced and exclude these cases from consideration. The first of such cases is $u > m$ — we take the white component of size $m$ as $\mathcal W\,'$ and $m$ black components of size $1$ as $\mathcal B\,'$; since $u > m$, there are still components remaining. The second case is $(u = m) \land ((t > u) \lor (s > 1))$ — we do the same to prove that $p$ is sub-balanced.

From $(4)$ it follows that the only remaining case is $u = m = t$, $s = 1$, i.e. $\mathcal W$ is a sole white component of size $t$, and $\mathcal B$ is a set of $t$ black components of size $1$. From $(2)$ it follows that $t > 1$. Let's prove that $t \le 3$. For this, we estimate the left-hand side of $(1)$ from below. The $t$ terms corresponding to black points are of no interest to us because $p_i = 0$ for them. Let $I$ be the set of the white vertex indices, $|I| = t$. For any $i \in I$, the difference $d_i - p_i$ is the number of black vertices adjacent to $v_i$ in $G$. It is at most $t$. Thus, $d_i = (d_i - p_i) + p_i \le t + p_i$ and $\frac {p_i}{d_i} \ge \frac {p_i}{t + p_i} = 1 - \frac t{t + p_i}$. Summing this for all $i \in I$ and using $(1)$, we get: $1 > t \left(1 - \sum_{i \in I} \frac 1{t + p_i}\right)$, hence

$$\sum_{i\,\in\,I} \frac 1{t + p_i} > \frac {t - 1}t\,. \tag{5}$$

$W_1$ is connected in $H$, therefore $\forall i \in I \colon p_i \ge 1$. Let's prove that $p_i > 1$ for at most one $i$. Indeed, otherwise $\frac {t-2}{t+1} + \frac 2{t+2} \ge \sum_{i \in I} \frac 1{t + p_i} > \frac {t - 1} t$ and we would get: $(t^3 - 4t) + (2t^2 + 2t)> t^3 + 2t^2 - t - 2$ and $2 > t$, whereas $t > 1$.

Now we know the structure of $W_1$, the subgraph induced in $G$ by the set of all white vertices: it is a star with $t$ vertices. If $t > 2$, and $v_i$ is its internal node, then $p_i = t - 1$ and $(5)$ turns into $\frac {t-1}{t+1} + \frac 1 {2t-1} > \frac {t-1}t$. From this, we conclude: $(2t^3 - 3t^2 + t) + (t^2 + t) > 2t^3 - t^2 - 2t + 1$, hence $3 > (t - 2)^2$ and $t = 3$.

What remains is to analyze 4-vertex and 6-vertex graphs of the designated structure. Note that each white vertex in them is adjacent to at least one black vertex because otherwise $d_i = p_i$ for some $i \in I$, which would contradict $(1)$. Moreover, at least one of the two white vertices for which $p_i = 1$, is adjacent to at least two black vertices because otherwise we would have two $\frac 1 2$ at the left-hand side of $(1)$. Let $x$ be such a vertex, $y$ be its white neighbour, and $z$ be a black neighbour of $y$. Since $x$ is adjacent to at least one black vertex different from $z$, we can swap the colors of $x$ and $z$ and obtain a placement that majorizes $p$. This concludes the proof.

Comment: Thank you, but I think your definition of majorization is different from the one in the problem. The definition in the problem is that every mark's score should not get lower (so the color matters), whereas your definition is only concerned with the entire score sequence.

Comment: @john is this answer right or wrong?

Comment: @mathworker21 I think I misunderstood original formulation and solved the problem for the case when each "score" is tied to a vertex, not to a mark. I'll keep my solution because it might give an insight for someone trying to solve the original problem, which is currently unsolved.

Comment: @JohnMcClane ok. you should edit your answer to say what you just said at the start